# Istio/envoy Rate limit when a specific source IP tries to reach a specific path

Tags: kubernetes, istio, rate-limiting, envoyproxy

I have implemented the global rate limiter on istio as per this doc - [Global Rate Limting with Istio](https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/policy-enforcement/rate-limit/#global-rate-limit). I am trying to figure out how to setup the descriptors in such a way that when a specific IP (x.x.x.x) tries to access a specific Path (/xyz) it gets rate limited immediately. If the same IP tries a different path or any other IP tries any path then 100 requests per minute are allowed

But my configmap and/or envoyfilter which I setup are wrong as I am not getting the expected output

Here is my configmap

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: ratelimit-config
data:
  config.yaml: |
    domain: frontend-ratelimit
    descriptors:
      - key: remote_address
        value: x.x.x.x
        descriptors:
        - key: PATH
          value: "/xyz"
          rate_limit:
            replaces:
            - name: src_ip
            unit: second
            requests_per_unit: 0
      - key: remote_address
        rate_limit:
          name: src_ip
          unit: minute
          requests_per_unit: 100
```

And here is the envoyfilter with the actions

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: EnvoyFilter
metadata:
  name: filter-ratelimit-svc
spec:
  workloadSelector:
    labels:
      istio: ingressgateway
  configPatches:
    - applyTo: VIRTUAL_HOST
      match:
        context: GATEWAY
        routeConfiguration:
          vhost:
            name: ""
            route:
              action: ANY
      patch:
        operation: MERGE
        # Applies the rate limit rules.
        value:
          rate_limits:
            - actions:
              - remote_address: {}
              - request_headers:
                  header_name: :path
                  descriptor_key: PATH
            - actions:
              - remote_address: {}
```

I've tried changing the configmap and envoyfilter with different action blocks and descriptors each time but I never seem to get both conditions working. It's always either one of the conditions which works as expected and the other one seems to fail

To better summarise what I am trying to achieve

1. When x.x.x.x tries to reach /xyz, allow 0 req
2. When x.x.x.x tries to reach any path, allow 100req/min
3. when y.y.y.y tries to reach any path, allow 100req/min

Answer (score 0):

One thing that I have noticed is that in your `filter-ratelimit-svc` file you have:

```
  value:
    rate_limits:
      - actions:
        - remote_address: {}
        - request_headers:
            header_name: :path
            descriptor_key: PATH
        - actions:
          - remote_address: {}
```

I had a similar issue, when I moved the `- remote_address: {}` from the first `action` and left only in the second action it worked.
The `filter-ratelimit-svc` would be this way:
value:

```
rate_limits:
  - actions:
    - request_headers:
        header_name: :path
        descriptor_key: PATH
    - actions:
      - remote_address: {}
```